# SystemJS: loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, systemjs

I'm using Angular2, and I'd like to include jQuery.

***systemjs.config.js***

```
(function (global) {
 System.config({
 paths: {
  'npm:': 'node_modules/',
  'jquery': "//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
 },
 meta: {
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
 },
.....
}
```

In ***app.module.ts***, I got the error : *Cannot find the module 'jquery'* when I put :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I try it using map instead of paths, but the same result..

Comment: TypeScript looks for packages into `node_modules` directory by default. Did you install jQuery with `npm`?

Comment: I already have jquery in **/dev/assets/js** folder not in  **node_modules**

Comment: That's why it doesn't work, TypeScript can find `jquery` and throws an error. With jquery it's actually more complicated and you need to install also its typings. If you're using TypeScript 2.0 you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

Comment: I've downloaded it, the **package.json** was updated but the same problem (nothing's changed) :/

Comment: What's your TypeScript version?

Comment: typescript : 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is:

```
import * as $ from 'jQuery';
```

Also should you be mapping to a CDN?

Why not get jQuery via NodeJS or save jQuery locally and map to it?

Comment: because I bought a template, and I have a lot of jQuery plugins... (I used the jQuery link just to make sure of path)

Comment: Actually, for SystemJS, and for compliance with ECMAScript, the correct code is `import $ from 'jquery'`; Callable module namespace objects are not supported by the spec and are largely a CommonJS interop hack provided by TypeScript.