# SystemJS: jquery_1.$ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, systemjs

I'm in the process of learning systemjs and the whole ES6 module backporting to older browsers.

As a educational piece i'm trying just to load jquery and do a simple "Hello world!" using `alert()`

Now, I got systemjs running up to a point where it loads typescript and jquery but is failing a few seconds after the page loads with the following error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) jquery_1.$ is not a function
    TypeError: jquery_1.$ is not a function
        at execute (http://localhost/webpMain/main.js!transpiled:12:22)
    Error loading http://localhost/webpMain/main.js
        at execute (http://localhost/webpMain/main.js!transpiled:12:22)
    Error loading http://localhost/webpMain/main.js
```

The page is just a huge red box, and if it gets clicked it's supposed to just alert "Hello world".

This is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
    <head>
        <title>SystemJS Test</title>
        <script src="node_modules\systemjs\dist\system.js"></script>
        <script src="system.config.js"></script>
        <style>
            #box {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </body>
    <script>

        System.import("app")
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

The systemjs configuration file:

```
System.config({

    paths: {
        "npm:*": "node_modules/*"
    },

    map: {
        app: 'webpMain',
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'jquery': 'npm:jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    },

    packages: {
        app: {
            main: 'main.js'
        }
    },

    transpiler: 'typescript',

});
```

And the `main.js`

```
import { $ } from "jquery";

$("box").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world!!");
});
```

- Any ideas why the jquery import is not working?
- What is displaying that error, typescript or systemjs?

Comment: $("box").click(function() {
        alert("Hello world!!");
    });

I think it should be: `$("#box")` since box is an id.
I never used systemjs so I'm not sure if

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't be an issue, if the selector is wrong just nothing should happen, a error should not occur.

Comment: right. the selector is an issue, but... that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763684/how-to-require-jquery-via-amd-in-typescript here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236090/systemjs-loading-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is

```
import $ from "jquery";

$("box").click(function() {
  alert("Hello world!!");
});
```

jQuery does not export anything named `$`.

Also since you are transpiling with TypeScript, your package config should look like

```
packages: {
  app: {
    main: 'main.ts',
    defaultExtension: 'ts'
  }
}
```

Currently you are transpiling twice.